# C# PipeStream Class - What exact is that class useful for?

Tags: c#, stream

I have no clue for what this class might be useful...I'm a totally beginner, maybe someone could explain me the use of pipestream in a easy way.

Thank you a lot

Comment: If you don't see a use for it, take a note somewhere and move on. Why does everything have to have an immediate use?